# TypeScript Type-related properties only?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this TypeScript code:

```
type MyType1 = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: string,
    prop3: string
}
type MyType2 = {
    prop1: number,
    prop2: string
}
const objOfType1 = { prop1: 1, prop2: "hello world", prop3: "should be removed" } as MyType1;
console.log('objOfType1', objOfType1);

const objOfType2 = objOfType1 as MyType2;
console.log('objOfType2', objOfType2);

const objOfType2Copy = { ...objOfType2 };
console.log('objOfType2Copy', objOfType2Copy);
```

The output in all 3 cases [is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWbxN.jpg)

objOfType1, objOfType2, and objOfType2Copy all have the same 3 properties. I was expecting that output for both objOfType2 and objOfType2Copy won't contain prop3 property.

How can I achieve the "expected" behavior?

Comment: Use a class. Compiler won't complain about extra properties on types and interfaces. You also seem to be confusing compile-time with run-time: the typescript compiler doesn't do things like remove properties from objects. All it does is tell you if your program adheres to the rules you've chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstanding how work Typescript.

Typescript is a superset of Javascript. It gives **static typing** which permit to check your code before the runtime and enforce code quality & understandability.

Typescript is **compiled** to Javascript. All the Typescript specific code is **removed** from the final JS code: all types. Your browser cannot run Typescript code, it runs the compiled Javascript one.

So your code compiled to JS gives something like that:

```
const objOfType1 = { prop1: 1, prop2: "hello world", prop3: "should be removed" }
console.log('objOfType1', objOfType1);

const objOfType2 = objOfType1;
console.log('objOfType2', objOfType2);

const objOfType2Copy = { ...objOfType2 };
console.log('objOfType2Copy', objOfType2Copy);
```

As you can see all types and references to them were removed: only stay the JS part. Typescript is only here to structure your code, he's the dev part.

When you use the `as` keyword, you just tell to the TS compiler "ok dude, this variable is THIS type". You don't modify anything about its value. It's just a static type cast.

**Typescript doesn't exist in runtime.** So when you code in Typescript, you have to always have in mind **"what this code is doing in runtime ?"**

Comment: That is a good answer which makes sense, thank you.